# How to pass an argument to 'isa' function in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to check a variable is existing in Matlab workspace, then check its class.
All thing was done by commands in m file.
In the case, the name of the variable is a symbolic or character, how I can use isa function.

```
a='x';
isa(a,'timeseries')
```

the above code is not worked, but if I change to

```
isa(x,'timeseries')
```

it is ok, so how I can check the class of an object by not directly pass its name?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `isa` like that because when you pass a string as the first argument to `isa`, the class of that string is a `char`

```
isa('x', 'double')
%   0

isa('x', 'char')
%   1
```

You *could* use `eval` to pass the *value* of `x` to `isa`

```
isa(eval('x'), 'double')
```

However the better approach is to explicitly get the class of the variable using `whos`

```
S = whos('x');
strcmp(S.class, 'double')
%   1
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the function `exist`: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/exist.html

```
if exist('x','var')
   class(x)
end
```

You pass a string with the name of the variable to `exist`. Once you have established it exists, you can use it in your `isa` call.

Comment: It does not work for my case, anyway, I want to pass 'x' or something convert to object name to use with 'isa', exist just check whether a variable is existing in workspace or not.

Comment: @greenworld: this answers your question as stated. You first need to use `exist` to check if a variable exists. Then you can use `isa` to see if it belongs to a particular class. It's not clear why you would need to pass a string name of the variable to `isa`. If you have a different question, please edit your question above.

Comment: Thank for your reply, however, I think my question is quite clear, passing an argument is described as follows:
"In the case, the name of the variable is a symbolic or characters, how I can use isa function"
In the other hand, when I wrote:
isa(x,'timeseries')
"it is ok"
it means that I know how to check a variable whether it is existing or not. Then your answer can not help me.
why do I need to do like that, because I want to process multiple variables with different classes which existing in the workspace.

Comment: I don't think your question is quite clear at all. 'isa' can only be used if the variable exists. If you want to check if a variable with the given name exists, you use 'exist' as I described. Note that you can pass a variable containing a string to 'exist'. Thus you can do 'exist(a,'var')', and then 'isa(eval(a),'timeseries')'.